# Metadata refinement display in SharePoint 2013

Tags: managed-metadata, 2013, managed-property, refinement-panel

I created a Site Column in my CT Hub that is a multi-value metadata field called ClientProjectType.  When I create the Managed Property in Search, I set as a text value and select the multi-value property.  After crawling, I add the field as a refiner.  However, it shows values in this pattern: ID;Title|GUID.

I need the display to be Title.  How do you resolve?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have the wrong crawled property mapped. In my case the site column was named Loan Type and that created the following 4 crawled properties

- Loan Type
- Loan_x0020_Type
- ows_Loan_x0020_Type
- ows_taxId_Loan_x0020_Type

I selected ows_Loan_x0020_Type and did a full crawl and it worked.